# Java Screen Scrape using sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, screen, scrape

I am trying to collect the HTML from this website http://movies.about.com/od/actorsalphalist/Actors_Detailed_Movie_News_Interviews_Websites.htm

I open a socket and try to read and print each line of the HTML page. When I run it I only get "EOF is false" and then "1" as the result.

I am not sure at all what is wrong as I know this should work in another example... Thanks a lot for your help!

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Twitter {

    static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 80;

    protected DataInputStream reply = null;
    protected PrintStream send = null;
    protected Socket sock = null;

    // ***********************************************************
    // *** The constructors create the socket and set up the input
    // *** and output channels on that socket.

    public Twitter() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        this(DEFAULT_PORT);
    }

    public Twitter(int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        sock = new Socket("movies.about.com", port);
        System.out.println(sock);
        reply = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
        System.out.println();
        send = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    }

    // ***********************************************************
    // *** forecast uses the socket that has already been created
    // *** to carry on a conversation with the Web server that it
    // *** has been contacted through the socket.

    public void forecast() {
        int i;
        String HTMLline;
        boolean eof, gotone;

        // *** This issues the same query that a Web browser would issue
        // *** to the Web server.

        try {
            send.println("GET /od/actorsalphalist/Actors_Detailed_Movie_News_Interviews_Websites.htm HTTP/1.1");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("about.com server is down.");
        }

        // *** This section parses the response from the Web server.
        // *** NOTE THAT "real" EOF does not occur until the Web server
        // *** has closed the connection.

        eof = false;
        gotone = false;
        while (!eof) {
            System.out.println("EOF is false");
            try {
                System.out.println("1");
                HTMLline = reply.readLine();
                System.out.println("2");
                System.out.println(HTMLline);
                System.out.println("Here?");
                if (HTMLline != null) {
                    System.out.println("its not null");
                }
                if (HTMLline == null) {
                    System.out.println("WTFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF");
                } else {
                    eof = true;
                    System.out.println("is it?");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("this exception happend");
                e.printStackTrace();
                eof = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // ***********************************************************
    // *** We need to close the socket when this class is destroyed.

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        sock.close();
    }

    // ***********************************************************
    // *** The main program creates a new Twitter class and
    // *** sends that class the command line args (via findNumber).

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Twitter aboutCom;
        DataInputStream cin = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        try {
            aboutCom = new Twitter();
            aboutCom.forecast();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't sent a valid HTTP request yet, so the server is still waiting for you to complete it. The GET line must end with \r\n, and you then need another one as a blank line to delimiter the request headers.

However you should be using URL, openConnection(), getInputStream() etc for this, rather than redundantly trying to reimplement HTTP yourself. All you get your way is a chance to get it wrong, as you are doing.

Comment: @RussellFyfe OK so use write() instead of println(), send the line terminator as \r\n yourself, and send it twice.